# Handling input form where input field is a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux

There is this dynamic form component.

Main.js

```
import RegistrationItemfrom "./RegistrationItem"
.......
         <Form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault();}}>
              <RegistrationItem
                inputtype="email"
                inputplaceholder="Email Address*"
                icon={faEnvelope}
              />
              <RegistrationItem
                inputtype="password"
                inputplaceholder="Password*"
                icon={faLock}
              />
             <button onClick={handleLogin()} > Login </Login>
        </Form>
```

File for input fields with styling and icons add to it.

RegistrationItem.js.

```
const RegistrationItem = () ={
return(
    <InputGroup className=" mb-4">
      <Input
        type={inputtype}
        name={inputname}
        id={inputid}
        placeholder={inputplaceholder}
        className="border-right-0"
      />
      <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
        <InputGroupText className="bg-transparent text-primary border-left-0">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-primary" icon={icon} />
        </InputGroupText>
      </InputGroupAddon>
</InputGroup>
)
}
```

How to implement submit of the form from the Login button `<button onClick={handleLogin()} > Login </Login>`

Comment: Its in the Main.js component.. The form is in the component but the input field in on another component.

Comment: Looks like you need to implement local state in your form component. And have the inputs update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code given we need two values. One is the email and the other is the password.

So two states needed to be added to the Form element email and password. These values need to be changed based on the change in the input.

So when the form is submitted these values can be used to perform whatever action is needed

The code could be like this if we are using only react and not other form libraries like react hook form

Main.js

import RegistrationItemfrom "./RegistrationItem"
.......

```
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password,setPasword] = useState('')

     <Form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault();handleSubmit(email,password,...otherArgs);}}>
          <RegistrationItem
            inputtype="email"
            inputplaceholder="Email Address*"
            icon={faEnvelope}
            value={email}
            setValue={setEmail}
          />
          <RegistrationItem
            inputtype="password"
            inputplaceholder="Password*"
            icon={faLock}
            value={password}
            setValue={setPassword}
          />
         <button type="submit" > Login </button>
    </Form>
```

RegistrationItem.js

```
    const RegistrationItem = ({inputtype,inputname,inputid,inputplaceholder,value,setValue,icon}) ={
return(
    <InputGroup className=" mb-4">
      <Input
        type={inputtype}
        name={inputname}
        id={inputid}
        placeholder={inputplaceholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)}
        className="border-right-0"
      />
      <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
        <InputGroupText className="bg-transparent text-primary border-left-0">
          <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-primary" icon={icon} />
        </InputGroupText>
      </InputGroupAddon>
</InputGroup>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Passing functions into compoments to get the value back. This will be helpful in other implementations too.

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to declare state and pass that to your child component and can update the state from child element and when you click on login you can use the state.

below i have shown you how you can declare the state and how you can pass it to your child element and in child element you can use it.
note : i have just passed it in your child component and over ther in argument you can see it so wherever you want to use them you can use it.


  const [registrationTypeValue,setRegistrationTypeValue]=useState("")
             <Form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault();}}>
                  <RegistrationItem
                    inputtype="email"
                    inputplaceholder="Email Address*"
                    icon={faEnvelope}
                    registrationTypeValue={registrationTypeValue}
                    setRegistrationTypeValue={setRegistrationTypeValue}/>
                  <RegistrationItem
                    inputtype="password"
                    inputplaceholder="Password*"
                    icon={faLock}
                  />
                 <button onClick={handleLogin()} > Login </Login></Form>
    
    
    const RegistrationItem = ({registrationTypeValue,setRegistrationTypeValue}) ={
    return(
        <InputGroup className=" mb-4">
          <Input
            type={inputtype}
            name={inputname}
            id={inputid}
            placeholder={inputplaceholder}
            className="border-right-0"
          />
          <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
            <InputGroupText className="bg-transparent text-primary border-left-0">
              <FontAwesomeIcon className="text-primary" icon={icon} />
            </InputGroupText>
          </InputGroupAddon>
    </InputGroup>
    )
    }
```

Comment: i just gave an example what you need to do.

create a state
pass it as props to children and use it

Comment: Please add the explanation in the answer itself, not in comments

Comment: sorry bro i missed it

Comment: You can still [edit] and update your answer